# ANOVA on population

Tags: population

I have the population data about the spread of animals in country (sheep, goat, cattle etc) by ranches.

Can i use ANOVA to see the difference between the means of animals by ranch type or can annova be only applied to a sample of the population
Note: the population distribution is not normal.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

From the [Wikipedia entry on statistical inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_inference):

> Inferential statistical analysis infers properties about a population: this includes testing hypotheses and deriving estimates. The population is assumed to be larger than the observed data set; in other words, the observed data is assumed to be sampled from a larger population.

From [PSU online course](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat504/node/16):

> Recall, a statistical inference aims at learning characteristics of the population from a sample; the population characteristics are parameters and sample characteristics are statistics.

If you are *truly* working with the population, you do not need to do ANOVA. You can compare the calculated means of different groups without any statistical tests because those calculated values are the *population* means.

It's worth thinking about what your population is. Maybe your data is just sample from a data-generating process (e.g. a snapshot in time) and you want to make inferences about the group means from that data-generating process.

Comment: I agree with you and yes I had been doing descriptive statistics on the population parameters

Comment: My data is a snapshot in time of the whole population,  so other than clustering, regression...is there any other statistical model i can use for data insights

Comment: If the population that you are interested in is animals in country (sheep, goat, cattle etc) by ranches *at any given time*, then you can consider your data set a sample (a snapshot) from that population and use ANOVA, regression, etc. This assumes the population is stationary over time.